# Sum of a series - proof of equality

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have no idea how to step forward with this problem:
Prove this equality:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln(\cos(\sin(\frac{k\pi}{2})) = {\lfloor {\frac{n-1}{2}} \rfloor}\log(\cos(1)) $$. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Hint: calculate a few terms, it should become apparent. Side note: is it supposed to be $\ln$ on both sides?

Comment: There is something wrong with this, since it implies that $\log \cos \sin(\frac{n \pi}2) = \log(\cos (1))/2.$

Comment: @IgorRivin how do you figure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $$\sum ^{n}_{k=1}\sin \dfrac{k\pi}{2}$$ We have $$\sin \dfrac{\pi}{2},\sin \pi,\sin \dfrac{3\pi}{2},\sin 2\pi,etc.$$ Which is $$1,0,-1,0 \text{ for a period of }2\pi$$ 
So
$$\sum ^{n}_{k=1}\ln[\cos(\sin \dfrac{k\pi}{2})]$$ Therefore becomes $$\ln {\cos(1)}+ \ln{\cos(0)}+\ln{\cos(-1)}+\ln{\cos(0)}...$$ And this equals to 
$$\ln{\cos^{m}(1)}=m\ln{\cos(1)}$$
Since $$\cos(0)=1 \text{ and } \ln{a}+\ln{b}=\ln{ab}$$
Where $$m =\begin{cases}\frac{n}{2} & n \text{ is even}\\\frac{n+1}{2} & n \text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$